# Can't Mimic Amazon Web Services Signature Algorithm

Tags: amazon-web-services, hmac

I'm becoming extremely frustrated when people & companies don't provide reliable documentation for their products.

According to this site: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

There is an algorithm that looks something like this:

```
import base64
import hmac
import sha
import urllib
h = hmac.new("OtxrzxIsfpFjA7SwPzILwy8Bw21TLhquhboDYROV",
             "GET\n\n\n1141889120\n/quotes/nelson",
             sha)
urllib.quote_plus(base64.encodestring(h.digest()).strip())
```

Which should produce a result of:

```
vjbyPxybdZaNmGa%2ByT272YEAiv4%3D
```

I've tried several variations, different charsets and different languages and I cannot produce this hash. I even downloaded some samples and when I use their signing algorithms they still don't produce this hash. Here's the C# code I have:

```
    byte[] bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("GET\n\n\n1141889120\n/quotes/nelson");
    byte[] secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OtxrzxIsfpFjA7SwPzILwy8Bw21TLhquhboDYROV");
    HMAC hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyBytes);
    byte[] hashBytes = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(bytesToSign);
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
```

But it produces a value of:

```
a5n2tpQTlqetX6Pjvv7vK23qi2JIZVlWZqIdteD2pok=
```

Yeah I can see that they're wrapping it with a URL encoder but that wouldn't change it this drastically. Does anyone have any idea what algorithm they may have used to produce this hash? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# code using the wrong HMAC hashing algorithm. From Amazon's documentation:

> "The hash function to compute the signature is HMAC-SHA1 defined in
>   RFC 2104 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt), using your Secret
>   Access Key as the key."

As it says, you need to use SHA-1 instead of SHA-256:

```
var bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("GET\n\n\n1141889120\n/quotes/nelson");
var secretKeyBytes = 
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OtxrzxIsfpFjA7SwPzILwy8Bw21TLhquhboDYROV");
var hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(secretKeyBytes);
var hashBytes = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(bytesToSign);
var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
```

Comment: Ugh. Thank you. I was using HMAC-SHA256 due to this: "You can use HMAC-SHA256 when you sign the request (we prefer HMAC-SHA256, but we still support HMAC-SHA1)" per: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1928

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is in the same document: You must set the SignatureMethod request parameter to either HmacSHA256 or HmacSHA1 to indicate which signing method you're using. You must set the SignatureVersion request parameter to 2